# What were the likely initial conditions at the time of the solar system's formation?

Tags: solar-system, grand-tack-hypothesis, nice-model

I know we will never know for sure how many planets there were and what their respective masses and orbital elements were when the solar system formed, but I'm very interested in what the approximate values of these quantities were when the protoplanetary disk had been dispersed. Of particular interest would be how closely together, i.e their semi-major axises, they formed since it is my understanding that the planets we see today ended up in their current orbits after a period of planetary migration.